# Change title for Categories page on custom component

Tags: development, joomla-4.x

I'm writing a component that will rely on Joomla's Categories to manage its own categories.

Everything's working OK, I just cannot figure out how to change my component's Categories list title.

I'd like to show "My Component Name or whatever: Categories" on the top title bar just like it happens with Articles and Banners Categories.

Thanks a lot!

[image: Custom Component categories]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

We must not use the string COM_MYCOMPONENT = "My component", as per the "component name", but the "extension name" as is shown on the url.

Given:

```
/administrator/index.php?option=com_categories&extension=com_mycomponent.somecategorytype
```

The language string must be COM_MYCOMPONENT_SOMECATEGORYTYPE on administrator/language/en-GB/com_mycomponent.ini

Thanks @Zollie and @Sharky for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a certain language string to the admin language file of your component. The most basic is simply the name of the component, for example `COM_CONTENT`. So in the language file you would add:

```
COM_CONTENT="Articles"
```

If you're using category sections in your component, append the section, e.g. `COM_CONTENT_ARTICLES`. You can optionally append `_CATEGORIES_TITLE` suffix to allow different string specifically in this view, since the generic ones are used in many other places where content types are needed. So `COM_CONTENT_CATEGORIES_TITLE` or `COM_CONTENT_ARTICLES_CATEGORIES_TITLE` also work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot get that to work.
Following your tip, I even searched com_banners.ini and com_banners.sys.ini for a string for "Banners: Categories", and could not identify it.

Can you please point how is that made on com_banners? (it's probably less confusing than com_content)

Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandrePaulo - what @Sharky is saying is when you place a language string into your **administrator/language -> en-GB -> com_mycomponent.ini** file for example: `COM_MYCOMPONENT="My Component"` then the **com_categories extension** automatically will take that string and add it before the word Categories and you'll get the title you are looking for.